# Python: How can I turn a list of tuples into dictionary keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, range

I know that I can create a list of tuples that track with list indices like this:

`my_tuples = [[(n,k) for n in range(10)] for k in range(10)]`

However, I would like to use these as dictionary keys. I tried this with:

`my_dict = dict(zip(my_tuples, some_other_iterable))`

This, of course, gave me an "Unhashable Type: List" error, which I should've expected.

Is there a way, other than using a double for loop, to do what I was trying to do above with dict and zip?

A little sample of what I am looking for would be:

`my_dict = {(0,0):None, (0,1):None, (0,2):None, (1,0):None, (1,1):None, (1,2):None}`

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you clarify: do you always want `None`, or do those values come from `some_other_iterable`?

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Yes, initially they will be set to None, until the function runs and changes them. So they'll start as None, but will end up differently, depending on the results of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to initialize a dict to a certain constant value given a list of keys, you can use the [`fromkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) method:

```
dict.fromkeys((n,k) for n in range(3) for k in range(3))
```

Which will give you:

```
{(0, 0): None,
 (0, 1): None,
 (0, 2): None,
 (1, 0): None,
 (1, 1): None,
 (1, 2): None,
 (2, 0): None,
 (2, 1): None,
 (2, 2): None}
```

Comment: maybe its worth mentioning that `fromkeys` can cause some "unexpected" behavior when the the second arg is `[]`

Comment: This won't work with "some_other_iterable" as OP asks in their question

Comment: @Nick -- see my comment (and answer) under the OP's question. I didn't think the question was clear, but I think that answer is.

Comment: Fair enough - the goalposts got moved post my answer.

Comment: @python_learner agreed, using a mutable default is probably not a good idea with `fromkeys()`.

Comment: Mark, thanks so much! This is super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `my_tuples` is a nested list of 10 sublists of 10 elements. If you flatten the list, it works fine. For example:

```
my_tuples = [(n,k) for n in range(10) for k in range(10)]
my_dict = dict(zip(my_tuples, [None] * 100))
print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{(0, 0): None, (0, 1): None, (0, 2): None, (0, 3): None, (0, 4): None, (0, 5): None, (0, 6): None, (0, 7): None, (0, 8): None, (0, 9): None, (1, 0): None, (1, 1): None, (1, 2): None, (1, 3): None, (1, 4): None, (1, 5): None, (1, 6): None, (1, 7): None, (1, 8): None, (1, 9): None, (2, 0): None, (2, 1): None, (2, 2): None, (2, 3): None, (2, 4): None, (2, 5): None, (2, 6): None, (2, 7): None, (2, 8): None, (2, 9): None, (3, 0): None, (3, 1): None, (3, 2): None, (3, 3): None, (3, 4): None, (3, 5): None, (3, 6): None, (3, 7): None, (3, 8): None, (3, 9): None, (4, 0): None, (4, 1): None, (4, 2): None, (4, 3): None, (4, 4): None, (4, 5): None, (4, 6): None, (4, 7): None, (4, 8): None, (4, 9): None, (5, 0): None, (5, 1): None, (5, 2): None, (5, 3): None, (5, 4): None, (5, 5): None, (5, 6): None, (5, 7): None, (5, 8): None, (5, 9): None, (6, 0): None, (6, 1): None, (6, 2): None, (6, 3): None, (6, 4): None, (6, 5): None, (6, 6): None, (6, 7): None, (6, 8): None, (6, 9): None, (7, 0): None, (7, 1): None, (7, 2): None, (7, 3): None, (7, 4): None, (7, 5): None, (7, 6): None, (7, 7): None, (7, 8): None, (7, 9): None, (8, 0): None, (8, 1): None, (8, 2): None, (8, 3): None, (8, 4): None, (8, 5): None, (8, 6): None, (8, 7): None, (8, 8): None, (8, 9): None, (9, 0): None, (9, 1): None, (9, 2): None, (9, 3): None, (9, 4): None, (9, 5): None, (9, 6): None, (9, 7): None, (9, 8): None, (9, 9): None}
```

As an example with an iterable:

```
my_tuples = [(n,k) for n in range(10) for k in range(10)]
some_other_iterable = range(100)
my_dict = dict(zip(my_tuples, some_other_iterable))
print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{(0, 0): 0, (0, 1): 1, (0, 2): 2, (0, 3): 3, (0, 4): 4, (0, 5): 5, (0, 6): 6, (0, 7): 7, (0, 8): 8, (0, 9): 9, (1, 0): 10, (1, 1): 11, (1, 2): 12, (1, 3): 13, (1, 4): 14, (1, 5): 15, (1, 6): 16, (1, 7): 17, (1, 8): 18, (1, 9): 19, (2, 0): 20, (2, 1): 21, (2, 2): 22, (2, 3): 23, (2, 4): 24, (2, 5): 25, (2, 6): 26, (2, 7): 27, (2, 8): 28, (2, 9): 29, (3, 0): 30, (3, 1): 31, (3, 2): 32, (3, 3): 33, (3, 4): 34, (3, 5): 35, (3, 6): 36, (3, 7): 37, (3, 8): 38, (3, 9): 39, (4, 0): 40, (4, 1): 41, (4, 2): 42, (4, 3): 43, (4, 4): 44, (4, 5): 45, (4, 6): 46, (4, 7): 47, (4, 8): 48, (4, 9): 49, (5, 0): 50, (5, 1): 51, (5, 2): 52, (5, 3): 53, (5, 4): 54, (5, 5): 55, (5, 6): 56, (5, 7): 57, (5, 8): 58, (5, 9): 59, (6, 0): 60, (6, 1): 61, (6, 2): 62, (6, 3): 63, (6, 4): 64, (6, 5): 65, (6, 6): 66, (6, 7): 67, (6, 8): 68, (6, 9): 69, (7, 0): 70, (7, 1): 71, (7, 2): 72, (7, 3): 73, (7, 4): 74, (7, 5): 75, (7, 6): 76, (7, 7): 77, (7, 8): 78, (7, 9): 79, (8, 0): 80, (8, 1): 81, (8, 2): 82, (8, 3): 83, (8, 4): 84, (8, 5): 85, (8, 6): 86, (8, 7): 87, (8, 8): 88, (8, 9): 89, (9, 0): 90, (9, 1): 91, (9, 2): 92, (9, 3): 93, (9, 4): 94, (9, 5): 95, (9, 6): 96, (9, 7): 97, (9, 8): 98, (9, 9): 99}
```

Comment: Nick, thank you so much! This is really helpful, and I will be adding this to my notes as well as Mark's answer. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @J.B. no worries - please see my edit for the situation where you did want to make the dict directly from an iterable

Answer (score 1):

Some tuples are hashable, like this

```py
>>> my_tuples
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]
>>> my_dict = {t:None for t in my_tuples}
>>> my_dict
{(0, 0): None, (0, 1): None, (0, 2): None, (1, 0): None, (1, 1): None, (1, 2): None}
```

Others are not. e.g.

```py
>>> my_tuples = [([0,1], [1,1]), ([0,2], [1,2])]
>>> my_dict = {t:None for t in my_tuples}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

my_tuples is a list of a list of tuples.

```
my_tuples = [[(n,k) for n in range(10)] for k in range(10)]
```

removing the parentheses will create a list of tuples

```
my_tuples = [(n,k) for n in range(10) for k in range(10)]
```

my_dict can be produced as you did it

```
my_dict = dict(zip(my_tuples, [None]*len(my_tuples))
```

or with a dictionary comprehension

```
my_dict = {x:None for x in my_tuples}
```

or

```
my_dict = {x:None for x,y in zip(my_tuples,[None]*len(my_tuples))}
```

Comment: Thanks, Josh. I am learning a lot! I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_tuples = [(n,k) for n in range(10) for k in range(10)]
x=dict()

for item in my_tuples:
    x[item]=None
```